# Meteor - errors after adding autoform package

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to add the autoform package to my meteor project. After running "meteor add aldeed:autoform" and adding the package - I am encountering the following errors:
Cannot find module 'mongo-object',
Cannot read property 'AutoForm' of undefined,
Uncaught ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined

I didn't even try to use the package. Just adding the package caused the errors. I am using Meteor 1.4.4.1

Any idea why this happens ? I followed the instruction in the autoform github repo.

Comment: and if you remove the package, the errors go away?

Comment: yes.. removing the package makes the errors go away

Comment: same here, downgrading the package to aldeed:autoform@5.8.1 seems to solve it for now

Comment: ```Autoform``` usually goes hand in hand with ```simple-schema``` and ```collection2```. Which versions of those have you installed? I believe autoform 6 and above only work with the npm version of ```simpl-schema```.

Comment: Just as a note: collection2 is also deprecated, collection2-core is the current package for that, it is also described in the collection2 README at github.

Comment: @tsahnar I described the new setup in my answer below, does it make your project run again?

Comment: yes thanks! it did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [installation for autoform 6](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#installation) says the following:

```
$ meteor add aldeed:autoform
$ npm i --save simpl-schema
```

Then you need (in v. >=6.0.0) to enable the use of autoform entries in SimpleSchema definitions. This is just required once, e.g. in your startup scripts:

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);
```

**What is not 100% clear to most people, switching to af6**

1. you need to remove the old aldeed:simple-schema package from the meteor packages
2. you need to switch from the deprecated collection2 to [collection2-core](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core)
3. you need to be aware of the [change log](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md#600), which indicates deprecated method and method name changes.

If you concern all of these changes it should run really fine again.

**Update March 2018:** `collection2-core` is now merged back to `aldeed:collection2` so use the latest version of this package.