# Adding aldeed:autoform causes error in Meteor 1.4.4.2

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I created a new app using below command;

```
meteor create --full test
```

The link application works fine. But then, I added ***aldeed:autoform*** to the project and re-run meteor.

the browser console shows error

```
Error : There is no route for the path: /
```

and the entire UI is blank.

**NOTE:** *When I remove the package, the application works fine.*

Comment: is the app using ```simple-schema``` ?

Comment: nope. The app is not using simple-schema. I also added it, but still problem persist.

Comment: simpl-schema also needs to enable autoform: `SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);`

Comment: I answered a similar issue with full details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836708/meteor-errors-after-adding-autoform-package/43976415#43976415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoForm 6.0 requires switching your app to using the **SimpleSchema package from 'NPM'** and `aldeed:collection2-core` package.

I encountered the same problem as yours, so when I ran command `npm install simpl-schema`, the error in the console went away.

> **Note:** The `aldeed:autoform` was also looking for `mongo-object` which is present in `simpl-schema` from NPM. For better understanding, follow the below image attached.

[image]

Hope this helps.